# Problem importing modules in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am working on **python** using the editor **Visual Studio Code**. The problem is that there are certain packages that are already installed on my MAC but the Visual Studio Code shows an error when I try importing the packages to my code. Few packages that show this error are: Pillow, pyserial, bs4,etc. I have downloaded the packages using the following pip command:

```
 sudo pip install Pillow
```

The packages are shown on my system when I use the command:

```
 pip freeze
```

Comment: check if you are installing and importing in the same environment.

Comment: I have created a virtual environment and am doing all this under the same virtual environment.

Comment: Install package again, do not use sudo. It's likely your problem. Also you need to make sure that your virtualenv activated both when installing and running the script. The easiest way to tell is by `which python` in your shell, or `print(sys.path)` in your python code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it worked without sudo.